# Is PDO ... SET NAMES utf8 dangerous?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8, database-security

Looking at here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

I understand that using

> SET NAMES utf8

is not a good idea, but it is not clear:

1. What is the issue?
2. How to avoid it?
3. Which is actually the solution to set the charset for a (or all) PDO connection(s) in a PHP 3.6 or higher?

The code I'm afraid is dangerous:

```
$this->_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host.name.blabla;dbname=my_database_name','username', 'password',array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
            ));
```

Thanks!

Comment: The linked page provides a pretty deep reasoning as to what are the implications. Please read!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you really still using PHP >= version 3.6 and < 5.3.6 ?

Assuming you have 5.3.6 or later...

[*Character sets*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)
 and [*PDO_MYSQL DSN*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)
say that you should use

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8",
               'my_user', 'my_pass');
```

And implies (not clearly enough) that `utf8` should be replaced by `utf8mb4` if appropriate.

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'` is not as good, but was the alternative before 5.3.6.

I think "dangerous" is too strong a word, even pre-5.3.6.

A related technique:  Using `init_command = SET NAMES ...` in `my.cnf` *is bad* because `init_command` is not executed when connecting as `root`.

`utf8mb4` is the preferred `CHARACTER SET` for UTF-8 because it includes Emoji and some Chinese characters that were missing from `utf8`.  That charset is available starting with MySQL version 5.5.3.

Comment: Oook, I'm actually using PHP 5.6. So your solutions must work... but I've tried both, utf8mb4 and utf8... without working. I'll give another shot. But if it is not actually dangerous, is going to stay as it is now (the code I've pasted before).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for extra info: In MySQL, `utf8mb4` is able to include Emoji and Chinese characters *because* it holds 4-byte and `utf8` only holds 3-byte. Emojis are of 4 -bytes.